# Chaining multiple function calls inside an if statement in C++ 17

Tags: c++

Let's say I have this as current code:

```
if (GetFlag(...)) {
  if (auto x = GetX(...)) {
     if (auto y = GetY(...)) {
         ...
     }
  }
}
```

and that the method calls and variable definitions need to be made in this order for both correctness and performance reasons (we don't want to calculate `x` if `GetFlag(...)` returns false, and we don't want to calculate `y` if `x` is `nullptr`).

Is there a way to refactor this into a "one-liner"? The closest I got to actually compiling would be

```
if (auto x = GetX(...); auto x = GetX(...) && GetFlag(...)) { ... }
```

but this does not preserve the order of operations.

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing wrong with that code (it is clear and explicit), one liners usually do not improve readability/maintainability.  And the compiler will not care either. So what do you want to achieve?

Comment: what benefit do you expect from refactoring into a single line? You have very explicit requirements, making your code equally explicit (maybe even with a comment to encourage others not to refactor and break these requirements) is a good idea

Comment: Hi guys. Thansk for caring about how well my code looks, but on the other hand, I think I made a valid technical question that could be answered on its own merits -- is it possible or not to oneline this?

Comment: Is the goal really to do a one-liner (questionable) or to reduce nesting (commendable)?

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the conditionals into a separate function that returns a tuple, and structured bind in the `if`

```
std::tuple<bool, std::optional<X>, std::optional<Y>> getFlagsXY()
{
    if (!getFlags())
    {
        return { false };
    }
    
    if (auto x = getX(); !x)
    {
        return { true, std::move(x) };
    }
    else 
    {
        return { true, std::move(x), getY() };
    }
}

if (auto [f, x, y] = getFlagsXY(); f && *x && *y) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

And yes it is possible.
If statements stop processing terms once they see which branch is going to be taken. Try changing the values of GetFlag, GetX to see when the body of the if gets called.

```
#include <iostream>

bool GetFlag()
{
    std::cout << "GetFlag\n";
    return true;
}

int GetX()
{
    std::cout << "GetX\n";
    return 0;
}

int GetY()
{
    std::cout << "GetY\n";
    return 3;
}


int main()
{
    int x;
    int y;

    if (GetFlag() && (x = GetX()) && (y = GetY()))
    {
        std::cout << "Do " << x << ", " << y;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (int x, y; GetFlag() && (x = GetX()) && (y = GetY()))`

Comment: You even could have `if (int x, y; GetFlags() && (x = GetX()) && (y = GetY())) { }` for a "real" one-liner. Though, this involves default construction of `x` and `y` (which is regardless for `int` but maybe relevant for a custom type). (Too bad, that the down-voter didn't leave a hint but that might've been one reason...)

Comment: Yes I forgot about initializers in if now being a thing. And yes I assumed this to be good enough for integral types.

Comment: @n.m.: That assumes same type for `x` and `y`...